# iText7.1 movePage resulting in errors: cannot move a page in partially flushed document

Tags: itext7

I need to move the table of contents from the last page to the third. I used to do this with iText7.0 by removing it, setting a PdfPage equal to what removePage returned, and then adding the page where I wanted it. However, it seems iText 7.1 changed this and removePage returns void now. I cannot just use movePage as it says it cannot move a page in partially flushed document.

iText7.0 code which works (the TOC page is the last page):

```
PdfPage page = pdf.removePage(pdf.getNumberOfPages());
pdf.addPage(3, page)
```

When iText7.1 is used, removePage does not return the removed page, so I do:

```
PdfPage page = pdf.getPage(pdf.getNumberOfPages()); 
pdf.movePage(page, 3)
```

I also tried

```
pdf.movePage(pdf.getNumberOfPages(), 3)
```

Either way, I got the same error message:

> com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException: Cannot move pages in partly flushed document. Page number 1 is already flushed.

Answer (score 3):

Using iText 7.1.2 and using the code below I was able to get this to work:

```
public static void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws Exception {
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src), new PdfWriter(dest));

    PdfPage page = pdfDocument.getPage(pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages());
    pdfDocument.movePage(page, 1);

    pdfDocument.close();
}
```

You could also do something like this:

```
public static void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws Exception {
    PdfDocument srcDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src));
    PdfDocument resultDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    resultDoc.initializeOutlines();
    List<Integer> pages = new ArrayList<>();

    int lastPage = srcDoc.getNumberOfPages();

    pages.add(lastPage);
    for (int i = 1; i <=lastPage-1; i++){
        pages.add(i);
    }

    srcDoc.copyPagesTo(pages, resultDoc);
    resultDoc.close();
    srcDoc.close();
}
```

Where you create a new PDF document and copy over the pages in order you'd like.
You can change this last code sample to be more generic but the general idea stays the same.
Depending on your usecase you could also save the altered PDF file to an OutputStream, close the original document and overwrite it. That way you won't have to deal with multiple files being created.

Comment: KevinWillems, Thanks so much.  The solution you provided works!  It seems there is no need to upgrade to 7.1.2.  I use 7.1.0 and I did not get any error with movepage.